# Getting image size, src, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not very good at JS. I have a problem and can't find the solution. this is my code which shows image just after putting it in input. I want to display them but also I need their size couse some of them need to be resized but other didn't. I found some codes with src of the picture but here I think the is no src. pictures may not be mine.

Is there way to get size without src or how to get it from this code?

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 600px; height: 400px" />

<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: Size as in bytes or width/height?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to get size in bytes and width/height.

You have to remove the width and height from the `img#uploadPreview` tag for it to work.

```
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        var element = document.getElementById("uploadPreview");
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;

        //total size in bytes
        var sizeInBytes = oFREvent.total;

        //for this to work, you have to remove the width/height from the img#uploadPreview element
        var imageWidth = element.width;
        var imageHeight = element.height;
    };
};
```